# Get output of minicom and cURL the result

Tags: run-script

I'm using Minicom with Linux and for the while, I specified a plain text file output like that in a screen:

```
screen -S minicom -d -m minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyS0 -C /path/to/file
```

I have Bash script too who is checking every new line in the plain text file.
If the bash script detects new line, I use this new entry to cURL it.

I would like to do the same process without a plain text file, but using runscript.
Indeed, I would like to get new entries and for every new entry, i would like to run cURL.

FYI, minicom output can be only composed by 13 or 26 characters.

How can I use expect ?

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards,

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show the code?

Comment: For a while, i dit not have any runscript because i don't know how to use it,
 specially with "expect"(if you are talking about runscript).

Comment: Can we "expect" a regular expression un runscript for minicom ?

Comment: I found how to execute script at the minicom starting.
But, I would like to get every COM input, and pass it to my script.

Example :

`#!/usr/bin/runscript

! /usr/bin/python myscript.py $arg1`